# How to set orientation to landscape in web?

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want my flutter web app to run in landscape mode.

Till now I have tried to add the following line in my main.dart

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  ]);
```

But I think the above code works for only the android or ios apps.

I have also set the orientation to landscape in my manifest.json file:-

```
"orientation": "landscape",
```

If anyone can tell me any way to do this in flutter or even by using JavaScript then also it will work.

Comment: Here is the answer, I used this for portrait orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Import import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

then put these lines of code in main dart and main method.

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);

runApp(myApp());
```

Comment: Appreciate your try, but i have already mentioned in my question that I have tried this and it does not work for flutter web apps.